# react native a11y: grouping elements for better voiceover announcement while still exposing inner accessible elements

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, accessibility, voiceover

As per my current understanding, VoiceOver announces things from left to right, top to bottom, as it assumes that is how a visual user sees content.

(I am yet to understand how voiceover figures out the order exactly, it certainly does not depend on the rendered layout tree. would appreciate any pointers )

In cases where you have an atomic piece of content across multiple rows which you want to be announced together by voiceover, you can group it by adding `accessible={true}` on the container view. The problem is, this makes any internal interactive elements unavailable for accessibility focus, and only allows a11y focus on this container view.

Consider the below design:

Two cards are shown side by side, each card has a title, subtitle and cta.
On screen reader focus,
we would ideally want the contents of the first card to be read first, and its CTA announced, and then move to the 2nd card and do the same.
What ends up happening with voiceover by default is that it announces title1, title2, subtitle1, subtitle2, cta1, cta2 which doesn't make sense for the user.

To fix this, one way is to make the container view accesible={true}, which has a side effect that the CTA is now unavailable to the accessibility focus, and hence a screenreader user can't reach or click the CTA.

Are there any preferred patterns to solve this?

[image]

EDIT: added example code for each card:

```
<View style={...} key={...}>
  <Text>{title}</Text>
  <Text>{subtitle}</Text>
  <Button flat secondary onPress={() => onPress(item)}>
    {cta}
  </Button>   
</View>
```

Comment: Would be great if you could share some code. I believe your `<View>` already has a grouping role and entering/leaving the group would be announced. You should probably not mark it as `accessible`, since you want to interact with the children, not the group. You state that VoiceOver announces both titles first, which seems weird. Did you set `accessible={true}` on the cards?

Comment: no i haven't set accesible true yet on the cards. if I do that, voiceover announcement is fine, but the internal button is not accessible anymore

Comment: no my view doesn't have a grouping role, is there any explicit group role?

Comment: The grouping role would be implicit, not necessary to declare it. What is the screen reader announcing? Again, it would be good if you shared some code. The button not being accessible is exactly the purpose of the `accessibility` property. You can interact with the card as a whole. What element are you using for the card? Did you try `<View>`?

Comment: added example code. I am already using view, and not setting the accessibility property to true. I am also not using any other accessibility property on the View

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to solve this,
The best and simplest one is using `ScrollView` component.

```
<ScrollView horizontal>
 <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false}>
   FirstCard
 </ScrollView>
 <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false}>
   SecondCard
 </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

`ScrollView` can help with defining direction without installing additional libs.

If you need specifc implementation, or `ScrollView` doesn't work for you can try these libs:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-a11y-order
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-a11y

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`UIAccessibilityContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/uiaccessibilitycontainer) and in particular the [`accessibilityElements`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements) property.

Those are both Objective-C objects and not react, but hopefully react allows you access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I can't offer an answer I've tested myself just yet as I'm investigating adding this into our project, I thought I'd drop this in for others as this Gist seems like the answer you need:

https://gist.github.com/louy/6b66c45ae47bb4e3bac5a104dd0649ff

It involves a creating a bridge to implement the commands in @slugolicious' answer from the JS/TS side.